# Can AJAX be used to load a module while the rest of the page is still loading?

Tags: php, ajax, joomla2.5

I'm writing a module for Joomla. It's going to be displaying data that it gets through a SOAP request. The problem with the SOAP request is that it can take up to 5 seconds to retrieve the data. This Joomla module will be on a page with many other Joomla modules and other content. I'm concerned that if this one Joomla module doing the SOAP request takes up to 5 seconds that it will delay loading the rest of the page. We have all been to websites which delay loading because of one part of the page and I don't want that to happen.

I am wondering if the solution is to have the Joomla module use AJAX (which I have no experience with yet) to do the SOAP request (currently it's being done with PHP) and somehow allow the rest of the page to load while it might take up to 5 seconds for the SOAP request to return data so it can be displayed.

What is a good workable solution for this problem? Caching the data isn't really an option because, it's timely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Ajax for this one.

Use window.onload() to trigger your ajax to fetch the data.  The only problem is that the whole page will load before you fetch your data, resulting in potential delays displaying final data.

The code will vary a lot depending on preference but the principle of ajax is:

1. Create a placeholder  or  with placeholder content (or nothing)
2. On an event (in this case page ready) request data.
3. When the data is ready, replace the placeholder content with your data.

This has an added advantage that you can use a 'refresh' button to trigger the change too, so users can request updated data without reloading the original page.

Ajax is well worth learning as it is a doddle either using jquery or simple js.  W3schools.com have an excellent tutorial.